# How to differentiate Joomla guest users

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I am developing a site in Joomla .
**I want to assign an unique status or id to guest user .This is needed to differentiate one guest user from other so that I can send the respective download link (after taking some inputs which may not be unique) to the respective guest user** .

But Joomla gives user_id = 0 to every guest user .

I am using [Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/5051) extension for embedding php .

Any idea for that !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J., You can use Joomla's session table. Joomla stores unique session_id for the each user even if for the guest. You just have to check guest =0 which means you will get session id of guest users only.